# Change the expand-icon of Vuetify's v-treeview to +/-

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<v-treeview
  :items="treeData"                                                             
  expand-icon="mdi-plus"                     
  activatable                  
  transition>                                    
</v-treeview>
```

Using Vuetify 2, I am not able to find a way to set the collapse-icon property in treeview. I found the customization for intermediate icon, but I need to change the toggle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treeview uses only one icon, which is set by the `expand-icon` property. Treeview then rotates the icon by -90° if the node is collapsed through these CSS rules:

```css
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle--open {
  transform: none;
}
```

If you want a different icon for expanded and collapsed state, you need to fiddle with the CSS. Something like

```css
/* disable rotation and hide original icon */
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle {
  transform: none!important;
}
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle > .v-icon,
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle > .v-icon__svg{
  display: none;
}
/* set a new icon*/
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle:before {
  content: '-';
}
.v-application--is-ltr .v-treeview-node__toggle--open:before {
  content: '+';
}
```

Note that this is only a draft, which probably needs quite a bit of additional work on the CSS so that it looks good and will not break something else.